# Adding auction bids to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a simple auction site. I am storing bids in their own MySQL table called 'bids'. I am wondering what is the best way of ensuring that two of the same bids are not submitted at the exact same time.

My current strategy for verifying that the bid submitted is in fact the highest bid is to do the following (as an example):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bids WHERE amount >= '".$bidamount."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO bids SET amount = '".$bidamount."'";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $bidid = mysql_insert_id();
}
```

The problem with the above set of queries is that between the time the SELECT query is run and the INSERT query is run, another user could insert the same bid.

Is there some way to lock the table during the SELECT that would prevent this double-bidding from occurring? My main concern with locking tables for such a purpose would be performance problems when you have a lot of people bidding at once.

Comment: Do you have a `when` field? If you store milliseconds in there, you could query based on that to verify that as of the time of the execution, it is the highest. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support datetime milliseconds, so you'd have to store it in another way.

Comment: I am completely naive as to the inner workings of MySQL, but shouldn't MySQL be taking care of locking tables when an insert is happening? This is posited to others reading this thread OP by the way, obviously both me and you do not know the answer.

Comment: How about putting a unique key on amount? You don't mention whether you distinguish between items / lots or whether the bid table is just for a single auction. Include 'item' or 'lot' if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to make conditional insert, like:

```
$amount = intval($amount);
$query = "
    INSERT INTO 
        bids(amount) 
    SELECT 
        {$amount} 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 1) tmp_tbl 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM bids WHERE amount >= {$amount}
    )
";
```

and check for affected (inserted) rows.

Comment: I have modified it a little, since it would fail when `bids` is empty, so temporary table with 1 row was introduced.